# Why is my JavaScript validator not working?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to make a validator using JavaScript to detect the number of numbers in a textarea, but it isn't showing anything at all.

```js
var number = document.getElementById("textarea");
var length = number.length;
if (length != 16) {
    document.getElementById("wrongOrRight").innerHTML = "Wrong credit card number! Please try again!";
}
else if (length = 16) {
    document.getElementById("wrongOrRight").innerHTML = "Correct number!";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("wrongOrRight").innerHTML = "Just to see if it works";
}
```

```css
textarea {
    border: 2px solid #0095FF;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
h4 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF.8">
    <title>Validator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter your credit card number here for chocolate! No scam!" cols="50" rows="1" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea>
<h4 id="wrongOrRight"></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a validator, not an authenticator.

Comment: You have no event listener to trigger any function.. Also your script isn't in a function so it will run upon page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct script that does what you are trying to achieve:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qh5jL6xt/)

You had few problems. Like mentionned by NewToJs in a comment, you had no event that linked your code to your textarea.

In order to achieve that, you needed to also make your code into a javascript function. Like this:

```
function validate() {
... //your code
}

<textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter your credit card number here for chocolate! No scam!" cols="50" rows="1" autofocus="autofocus" onkeyup="validate()">
```

Another problem is that you compared the length of the textarea, and not the value of the textarea. Here is what you needed to do : 
`var number = document.getElementById("textarea").value;`

Next, when you compared the length of the number to 16, you did

```
 } else if (length = 16) {
```

You forgot a = (a comparison in javascript is ==). I believe it was a typo, but it is fixed in my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add:

```
onChange="ChecktheInput();"
```

to you text area input and code your java script in the fuction:

```
function ChecktheInput() {
// your validation code
}
```